# IE11 CSS alternative to "unset"

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-11

I have a fixed div on my page which is positioned with the following CSS properties:

```
width: 320px;
height: 160px;
position: fixed;
right: 15px;
bottom: 15px;
top: unset;
z-index: -1;
```

The div appears fine in the bottom right of the page in other browsers, but in Internet Explorer 11 the div appears in the top right. I believe this issue is coming from `top: unset;` which doesnt appear to be supported in IE.

Are there any workarounds using CSS or JS that could be used to achieve the same positioning?

Comment: Did you try `none` or `initial`? Without more code it's difficult to know if they work to you

Comment: You can use the `auto` value if you want it to go to the default value.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You are looking for `top: auto`, it seems.

Comment: Yes, for all intents and purposes, just hardcoding the initial value of auto will work. top is not inherited, which makes top: unset equivalent to top: initial and therefore equivalent to top: auto.

Comment: IE11 behaviour disobeys the spec - unless a valid value is supplied (if an invalid value, like `unset` is supplied, the rule is/should be ignored) then the default value of `auto` should be applied: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#propdef-top

Comment: @Adam Hold on, isn't `unset` a valid value, just like `initial`? Also see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) where unset is given as an example of a global value. In addition, see the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) on `unset` itself. *It can be applied to any CSS property [...]*

Comment: Using `top: auto` instead of `unset` appears to have resolved the issue on IE11 without affecting its appearance on other browsers

Comment: @BramVanroy - good point, my comment was wrong. So the value of `unset` should behave like `initial` in the context of the `top` rule - and the `initial` value for top is `auto`....so IE11 is still wrong according to the spec, but not for the reason I stated.

Comment: @Adam I am confused, though. When looking up [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) (as a keyword value; different from *the initial value* of a property), the compatibility sheet says that it's not supported by Internet Explorer. So I'm guessing IE ignores that line, but still - it should then default to `auto` as well. I'm not sure why IE does this.

Comment: @BramVanroy 'padding : unset;' was not working for me, anyway this helped me, thanks. But, when I am inspecting the element in IE, I am seeing that in 'padding : auto;' "auto" was getting red underlined, any reason for that?

Comment: @ShravilPotdar Please post a new question. It is different from this one.

Answer (score 35):

While `top:auto` will work in the case of `top`, it should be mentioned that `auto` is not simply an "IE equivalent" to `unset` or `initial`.

For example, the initial value for `max-width` is `none` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)). And the initial value for `background-color` is `transparent` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color)). Each CSS property has an initial value, and for IE it must be explicitly set.

Initial values are listed on sites such as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference), and [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp) (where they are called "default values").

With a question title like **IE11 CSS alternative to “unset”** many people will find this page from a search engine who have needs that differ from OP's. So I think an explanation of how to look up initial values is more valuable than a "just use this" type of answer.

Comment: Thank you for the MDN source, didn't know that they list the initial value for every CSS property. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `top: auto` didn't work, I had a bottom value instead. The default value is `position: static` and this worked for me in IE 11.

Comment: then you should use `bottom: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

The default value is `static`.

I was having the same issue, so I changed

`position: unset;` to `position: static;`

In your case you can use `top: static;`

Comment: The default value for `position` is `static`, but it is neither the default value nor a valid value for `top`.